# Cordova add android error

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I trying add cordova android app and getting a json parsing error.

I think that it is cordova error, because I can create and test my projects with ionic and phonegap at Android Emulator.

```
C:\>cordova create hello hello.cd.cm HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "hello.cd.cm" at lo
cation "C:\hello"

C:\>cd hello


C:\hello>cordova platform add android -verbose
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
CordovaError: Unable to fetch platform android: Error: Failed to parse json
Unexpected token
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordo
va-lib\src\cordova\platform.js:194:15
    at _rejected (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.j
s:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node
_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.j
s:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_module
s\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Help me please.

**UPD:
I degrade cordova from 4.3.0 to 4.2.0 and it works now. But it is not normal of course...**